# Why is an even-odd split 'faster' for MergeSort?

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o, mergesort

> MergeSort is a divide-and-conquer algorithm that divides the input into several parts and solves the parts recursively.
>
> ...There are several approaches for the split function. One way is to split down the middle. That approach has some nice properties, however, we'll focus on a method that's a little bit faster: even-odd split. The idea is to put every even-position element in one list, and every odd-position in another.

This is straight from my lecture notes. Why exactly is it the case that the even-odd split is faster than down the middle of the array?

I'm speculating it has something to do with the list being passed into MergeSort and having the quality of already already sorted, but I'm not entirely sure.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Edit: I tried running the following in Python...

```
global K
K = []
for i in range (1, 100000):
    K.append(i)


def testMergeSort():
"""
testMergeSort shows the proper functionality for the
Merge Sort Algorithm implemented above.
"""

t = Timer("mergeSort([K])", "from __main__ import *")
print(t.timeit(1000000))

p = Timer("mergeSort2([K])", "from __main__ import *")
print(p.timeit(1000000))
```

(MergeSort is the even-odd MergeSort, MergeSort2 divides down the center)

And the result was:

> > > 0.771506746608
> > >
> > > 0.843161219237

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the advantage is when merging the sorted sublists back together ... could it relate to parallellisability of the algorithm?

Comment: How about asking at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Merging two sorted lists means iterating the lists once, so it looks like O(n) to me.  Not sure if the merge could be easily parallelised.  As for the split, I have no idea why allocating two sub-lists, iterating the list, moving values into alternate lists, checking to see if at end of list etc etc. might be considered faster than 'shr 1' <g>.

Comment: If this comes from your lecture notes, why not simply ask your instructor?

Comment: I took this course in the winter.

Comment: @Unsure The quote from your notes doesn't say "array" anywhere. Are you sure you're not dealing with linked lists, where the advantage is clear?

Comment: Michael, you are correct. It really doesn't have anything to do with *what* the list looks like. Under the hood, I suppose Python handles it differently when you are adding elements based on even/odd index, when compared to splitting the list (where a length calculation is necessary on the array). Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @Unsure Python lists are arrays, not linked lists, so your timing results are pretty interesting. How did you implement the splitting?

Answer (score 1):

I can see that it could be possible that it is better because splitting it with alternative elements means you don't have to know how long the input is to start with - you just take elements and put them in alternating lists until you run out.

Also you could potentially starting splitting the resulting lists before you have finished iterating through the first list if you are careful allowing for better parallel processing.

I should add that I'm no expert on these matters, they are just things that came to mind...

Comment: In other words, even/odd splitting can be performed _online_ versus offline.

Answer (score 1):

The closer the input list is to already being sorted, the lower the runtime (this is because the `merge` procedure doesn't have to `move` any of the values if everything is already in the correct order; it just performs *O*(*n*) comparisons.  Since MergeSort recursively calls itself on each half of the split, one wants to choose a `split` function that increases the likelihood that the resulting halves of the list are in sorted order.  If the list is *mostly* sorted, even-odd split will do a better job of this than splitting down the middle.  For example,

```
MergeSort([2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 7])
```

would result in

```
Merge(MergeSort([2, 1, 4]), MergeSort([3, 5, 7]))
```

if we split down the middle (note that both sub-lists have sorting errors), whereas if we did even-odd split we would get

```
Merge(MergeSort([2, 4, 5]), MergeSort([1, 3, 7]))
```

which results in two already-sorted lists (and best-case performance for the subsequent calls to `MergeSort`).  Without knowing anything about the input lists, though, the choice of splitting function shouldn't affect runtime asymptotically.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is noise in your experiment. :) Some of it may come from compare-and-swap not actually moving any elements in the list which avoids cache invalidation, etc.

Regardless, there is a chat about this here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6732/why-is-an-even-odd-split-faster-for-mergesort/6764#6764 (and yes, I did post a similar answer there (full disclosure))

The related Wikipedia articles point out that mergesort is O( n log(n) ) while Odd-Even Merge Sort is O( n log(n)^2 ). Odd-Even is certainly "slower", but the sorting network is static so you always know what operations you are going to perform *and* (looking at the graphic in the Wikipedia entry) notice how the algorithm stays parallel until the end.

Where as merge sort finally merges 2 lists together the last comparisons of the 8-element sorting network for Odd-Even merge sort are still independent.